# Does telekinesis/psychokinesis add Strength dice to wielding weapons?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension

If you have a psychic with Telekinesis/Psychokinesis in oWoD, can you use the telekinetic Strength value for a damage roll on a melee weapon attack (assuming requisite attack/TK rolls succeed)? Would you consider replacing your physical strength, or adding it?

I understand we're going well into potential House Rules territory, but the rules in the books that I read are pretty lean in this specific regard. I'd like to at least have a basis for what I propose to the GM before we chat about it.

For more detail, I would like to create a Mortal+ that is specifically a "zen fighter" who uses mental potency and concentration to aid in combat effectiveness. This isn't ancillary to the character (e.g. a loophole or cheat), it's literally the core concept at stake.

Edit: For further specification, it was accepted during a campaign once by splitting the dice pool, rolling Psychokinesis, then rolling the attack (if it's all done in the same action). So it's already penalized by a lower die count in that regard. Seems legit, but there's some rules lawyering about Psychokinesis only applying to objects (arbitrary, but rules is rules). It gets a little sticky.

Comment: Were it my campaign I would allow the player to replace strength with the TK Pool for damage indicating an extra push provided by the mind.

Answer (score 2):

## This is not possible, by rule

You cannot split your dice pool to get two rolls on the same action.  Just at that point, what you are trying to do is going against the word and spirit of the rules.

You can attack with Psychokinesis (Sorcerer, page 105), but the attack uses wits instead of dexterity.  Melee damage from such attacks is the Psychokinesis strength only (ie. your Psychokinesis level - 1).

You cannot, by rule, without getting into house rule nonsense, use your Psychokinesis to augment your physical strength.  Again, that would require two rolls for one action, and not even supernatural means of getting extra actions allows this.

### How you are trying this

But playing devils advocate, how could you attack physically and psychokinetically in the same round?  It depends on what part of you has the weapon at the time.  If it is in your hands, you would have to attack with your physical body, drop the weapon, gain control of the weapon with Psychokinesis, then attack with it.  If you ST is generous, that's three actions.

### How it's been done

So you want to make a zen fighter mortal?  Drink some vampire blood, then kill the vampire.  You get one level of Potence untrained, for free, which is an automatic success on a strength roll per level.  This is how this type of mortal character has been created throughout the history of oWoD, back to 1992's The Hunter's Hunted.

Comment: I was interpreting the usage as (for example) using telekinesis to help give the head of an axe (being wielded otherwise normally) an extra push; or effectively lightening the axe so the wielder can swing it harder.

Comment: @Uueerdo You cannot split dice pools for mental and physical actions.

Comment: Ah, I didn't recall that, and couldn't find the reference; the the "multiple actions" panel in VtM Revised (I know, not MtA, but I would imagine those parts are similar/identical) mentions nothing about mental vs physical either. _However, the total pool penalty would be five, minus two for the "first" action, and minus three for the "second" one; so the unmodified psychokinesis pool would've had to be at least five to be much , if any, of a benefit._

Answer (score -1):

I'd agree with UhlBelk's comment; replace strength with the Telekinesis pool for mêlée damage. As you say, though, it's really in house rules territory. Up to the individual GM. That said, if it's part of the player's core concept, it should be allowed unless it's somehow abusing the system rules.